# How to access ITunes Store in foreign country

Tags: itunes, apple-id

Suppose I have an AppleID linked to my credit card in my country. Now I would like to browse the ITunes Store of *another* country.

I know I have to create another AppleID linked to a credit cards (or any other payment option) of that country. However I do not have such a credit card.

My question is: Can I browse or/and consume content in the ITunes store of a foreign country, where I have no credit card, bank account, etc. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the country you will plan to open the account on.

For example, if you want to open an account on US or UK, you could select `None` as payment method. [Payment methods you can use in the iTunes Store, Mac App Store, App Store, and iBooks Store](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT5552), [same website for UK](http://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT5552).

If you want to open in in Spain, you don't have this option. [¿Qué métodos de pago puedo usar en el iTunes Store?](http://support.apple.com/es-es/HT5552).

Best option is to open any websites I post before, go to the bottom of the page, select the country you want and check available options.

Comment: Go onto iTunes and pretend to "Buy" a free app/music. you will be prompted to create an account and the option of `None` will be avaliable in the US/UK, like jherran said. Creating the account before purchasing wouldn't let you choose `None` as an option.

Answer (score 1):

You can browse any store without an account. If you scroll to the bottom of the iTunes Store home page, there is a link for Change Country. But without an account, you won't be able to purchase anything. See jherran's answer about options for obtaining an account.